# Memory leak in mongo-java-driver v 2.12.0

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, memory-leaks

**Env:**

Java: 1.8

Mongo db: 2.6.7

Mongo-java driver: 2.12.0

Apache-Tomcat: 7.0.53

**Error**

I get these errors when I am closing the connections in mongo cursor. These are potential memory leaks.

**Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
        at org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:374) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:645) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:454) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar:na]
.......
```

Any fix available?

Comment: If you believe this to be a bug in the driver then you are better of opening a bug as described here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver#bugs--feature-requests

Comment: Martin is right; furthermore, if you want us to try and check your conclusion, you should include enough of the code that generated those exceptions for us to understand it.